# Perform custom SQL query with Google Cloud Data Fusion

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-data-fusion

I have data pipelines that consist of multiple SQL queries being run against BigQuery tables, I would like to build these in Google Cloud Fusion, but I don't see an option to transform/select with custom SQL.

is this available, or am I misinterpreting the use cases for this tool?

Comment: can you please share more details about how you connect from  Google Cloud Fusion to BigQuery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is now a native BigQuery Execute action that allows SQL queries to run as part of a Data Fusion Pipeline.

[image]

This job is an action, see below from the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/concepts/overview):

> Action plugins define custom actions that are scheduled to take place
>   during a workflow but don't directly manipulate data in the workflow.
>   For example, using the Database custom action, you can run an
>   arbitrary database command at the end of your pipeline. Alternatively,
>   you can trigger an action to move files within Cloud Storage.

Answer (score 4):

A new Action plugin is being added that would allow you to specify a SQL to run in BQ. Expect the connectors to be available in Hub by mid May.

Nitin

Comment: Can you please share the official page that assures SQL support?

Comment: I can't find this, is it available?

Comment: @BenP this has been merged and would be available next month

Comment: Thanks @NitinMotgi - what is the name of the action? Is it a part of the GCS addon, or stand alone?

Comment: Anyone know if this has been released yet?

Comment: @crazy8 There is a now a BigQuery action which fulfills this requirement.